# Need to support different screen size and different screen resolutions in android

Tags: android, image, drawable, resolution, screen-size

I was just developing an application in android that works with both phone and tablet.
now the problem i am facing is with the icon sizes, if i am using say 28dp for mdpi devices then i came across one issue. In my office we have one 8inch tablet coming under mdpi and 5 inch phone also in mdpi. so both devices uses the same icon with size 28 dp. How to solve this problem?

Same in the case of text size i am facing the same issue. Is der any solution for this? I hav read many documentation so please dont copy paste urls. Kindly help me with exact solution...

Comment: That's not a problem

Comment: @darnmason not problem for?